# Having trouble with a mere connectionstring in c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, localhost

Ok, so I'm doing a website in .Net and for one of my validators, I'm trying to connect to my database. It's a database that I created in my App_Data folder, so it's a local one. The thing is, I have the following on my C# file:

```
 SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection();
        db.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\baseDados.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        db.Open();
//MORE CODE
```

I've got an error on my ConnectionString. Can't I use the same connectionstring that the one in my web.config file? I have been looking to how to connect to my database, but none of the solutions worked for me 'till now. I'm probably overlooking something. Thanks. :)

Comment: What error do you get? And did you try to pass the string directly in the constructor?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that one: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: O formato da cadeia de inicialização não está em conformidade com a especificação no início do índice 59. (In english, it says that a certain "format" does not correspond with the specification in the beginning of index 59... The hell is that? xD)

Answer (score 0):

|DataDirectory| is a pointer in the config that gets replaced by the actual location of the database. You are using an attached database, so it is looking for the actual directory the data file is located in.

My suggestion, as it is more likely to be like production, is attach the database file to the database server. Since it is .mdf, I am guessing SQL Server (99.9% sure it is SQL Server). You will then alter your database connection string to point to the server, database name, etc. The main change will be the center section. The other option is find the actual location of the file and attempt from there. This should work, as that is what the server does for you when it pulls from config.

I don't have time to look, but I bet there is something in config that points where that file is, or it is automatically stored in a specific location by the framework. A quick Google search should yield answers.